# Медленная отрисовка прямоугольников в WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть программа, в которой я создаю фигуры с помощью FillRectangle, кликая на форму. При зажатии кнопки мыши над фигурой, я отрисовываю вокруг нее рамку с помощью FillRectangle и перемещаю ее перемещением мыши. При перемещении происходит перерисовка всех объектов, при этом все объекты, которые в списке находятся после выбранной фигуры, отрисовываются с мерцанием. Если не отрисовывать рамку вокруг выбранной фигуры, то мерцания нет. В чем может быть проблема и как можно убрать мерцание? P.S. Двойная буферизация включена.
Код формы:

```
Graphics graphics;
bool butClamped = false;
Element selectedItem;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
}
public void ReDraw()
{
    this.Refresh();
    editor.Draw(graphics);//отрисовка всех объектов
}
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    selectedItem = editor.HitElement(e.X, e.Y);
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && selectedItem != null)
    {
        editor.ChooseItem();
        butClamped = true;
    }
}

private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        butClamped = false;
}

private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (butClamped)
    {
        selectedItem.ChangeCoord(e.X, e.Y);
        ReDraw();
    }
}
```

Код фигуры:

```
public override void Draw(Graphics graphics)
{
    graphics.FillRectangle(brush, X, Y, width, height);
    if (selected)
    {
        graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, X, Y, width, height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась отрисовка в событии Paint

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).